# Execute ghc-mod fail when .cabal file in current directory

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghc-mod

When I execute `ghc-mod version` normally, It will print the infomation like this:

```
ghc-mod version 5.0.1.2 compiled by GHC 7.8.3
```

But if .cabal file was in current directory, It will print the error message like this:

```
cabal configure failed: user error (cabal configure (exit 1)
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
HUnit -any, hspec -any, testloop -any
)
```

How should I fix this probleam?

Comment: what would your expected behaviour look like when there is a problem with your cabal-project? Is the question how you can fix the problem in this case or in general? (BTW: in this case I would recommmend `cabal sandbox init` and `cabal install --dependencies-only` this should be save and solve your problem

Comment: @CarstenKönig I just want to get the version information of ghc-mod, I think it should return the right message whether there is a problem with the cabal-project.

Comment: oh - sorry missed the version there - I think you might have to fill in a [bug-report](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues) / request in this case

Comment: Looks like you're seeing [the same bug I reported last week](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/353).